# Syntax question about `HAVING` in writing a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am learning mysql 8.0. A problem in the CodeSignal website asks me to write a query. The problem description is:

You want to expand your movie collection, but you don't really have any preferences so you're not sure where to start. After some consideration, you decide that you should start by finding more movies from award-winning directors whose movies you already own and who have shot a movie somewhat recently.

To find the directors whose movies you might want to consider watching in the first place, you've created a database of all the films you already own and stored them in a `moviesInfo` table, which has the following structure:

- `title`: the title of the movie;
- `director`: the director of this movie;
- `year`: the year the movie was released;
- `oscars`: the number of the Academy Awards this movie received.

Given the `moviesInfo` table, compose the list of directors you should consider watching more movies from. The resulting table should have a single director column and contain the names of film directors such that:

- they shot movies after the year 2000;
- the total number of Oscar awards these movies received is more than 2.
- The table should be sorted by the directors' names in ascending order.

[image]

My first solution is:

```sql
SELECT director FROM moviesInfo
GROUP BY director
HAVING (year > 2000
AND SUM(oscars) > 2)
ORDER BY director ASC;
```

which throws an error: `Unknown column 'year' in 'having clause'`. After some research, I found an explanation for this error: *The HAVING clause must contain an expression or column that’s listed in the SELECT clause.*

One possible correct solution is:

```sql
SELECT director FROM moviesInfo
WHERE year > 2000
GROUP BY director
HAVING SUM(oscars) > 2
ORDER BY director ASC;
```

However, the `oscars` column after `HAVING` does not appear in the SELECT clause either. **My question is:** why does the sql interpreter not complain about it?

Comment: hint: you don't use `oscars` column in having, you're using `sum(oscars)`

Comment: ohh, so it means after HAVING, we can use aggregated results from columns not mentioned in SELECT?

Comment: yes, this is exactly why having exists, it filters after group by, while `where` filters before

Comment: In a way, `WHERE` filters column, whereas `HAVING` filters aggregates.

Comment: The explanation you found isn't entirely true, you can use `expressions` in the having clause (e.g. the expression `SUM(oscars)` ) that are not present in the select clause. nb: You could place that same expression into the select clause i.e. `select director, sum(oscars) as oscars` but it is NOT mandatory that you do so. Note also that the where clause (in addition to the comments above about being different to having clause) also allows you to refer to columns that are not in the select clause.